# Unable to get profiling status on MongoDb Shell

Tags: mongodb

MongoDb consist of a database auditTrails having only one collection named entities. collection.count() return 2049823 but when i try to get the profiling status using db.getProfilingStatus(), following error is returned at mongo shell:

uncaught exception: profile command failed: {

```
"assertion" : "Can't take a write lock while out of disk space",

"assertionCode" : 14031,

"errmsg" : "db assertion failure",

"ok" : 0
```

Comment: Your out of disk space...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sammaye mentioned, you are out of diskspace.